# unable access assets file android

Tags: android, pdf, assets

Hi I am developing android application in which I have assets folder. Inside assets folder I have put abc.pdf. But when I tried to access that file it shows me file not exists. I tried it in following way.

```
 File pdfFile = new File("file:///android_asset/"+ "abc.pdf");
    if(!pdfFile.exists()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "not there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "it's there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An asset is only a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device. You cannot reference it using `File`.

Use `AssetManager` and `open()` to get an `InputStream` on the asset. You can get an `AssetManager` by calling `getAssets()` on any `Context` or `Resources` object.

Answer (score 0):

For example, load json file from assets folder:

```
private String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context) {
    String json;
    try {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("model.json");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
        json = writer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```